# Sublime SQL REGEX highlighting

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I'm trying to modify an existing language definition in sublime

It's for SQL

Currently `(\@|@@)(\w)*` is being used to match against local declared parameters (e.g. `@MyParam`) and also system parameters (e.g. `@@Identity` or `@@FETCH_STATUS`)

I'm trying to split these into 2 groups

System parameters I can get like `(\@\@)(\w)*` but I'm having problems with the local parameters.

- `(\@)(\w)*` matches both @MyParam and @@Identity
- `(^\@)(\w)*` only highlights the first match (i.e. @MyParam but not @MyParam2

Can someone help me with the correct regex?

Comment: @Unihedron escaping or not escaping doesn't affect the result in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below regex to capture local parameters and system parameters into two separate groups.

```
(?<=^| )(@\w*)(?= |$)|(?<=^| )(@@\w*)(?= |$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yZ5pE6/1)

**Update:**

Sublime text 2 supports `\K`(*discards the previous matches*),

```
(?m)(?:^| )\K(@\w*)(?= |$)|(?:^| )\K(@@\w*)(?= |$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yZ5pE6/3)

[image]

[**Explanation:**](http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl?re=%28%3Fm%29%28%3F%3A%5E|+%29%5CK%28%40%5Cw*%29%28%3F%3D+|%24%29|%28%3F%3A%5E|+%29%5CK%28%40%40%5Cw*%29%28%3F%3D+|%24%29&.submit=Explain!&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode)

```
(?m)                     set flags for this block (with ^ and $
                         matching start and end of line) (case-
                         sensitive) (with . not matching \n)
                         (matching whitespace and # normally)
(?:                      group, but do not capture:
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
 |                        OR
                           ' '
)                        end of grouping
\K                       '\K' (resets the starting point of the
                         reported match)
(                        group and capture to \1:
  @                        '@'
  \w*                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or
                           more times)
)                        end of \1
(?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
                           ' '
 |                        OR
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                           "line"
)                        end of look-ahead
|                        OR
(?:                      group, but do not capture:
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
 |                        OR
                           ' '
)                        end of grouping
\K                       '\K' (resets the starting point of the
                         reported match)
(                        group and capture to \2:
  @@                       '@@'
  \w*                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or
                           more times)
)                        end of \2
(?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
                           ' '
 |                        OR
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                           "line"
```

Comment: I see it works in the Demo, but it doesn't look as though sublimetext allows for look behinds